# Is there a way to prevent applications from updating when running on battery

Tags: google-play-store, updates, battery

I know you can restrict applications to update on Wi-Fi only.
Can you achieve the same thing with "update when charging on sector only" too?

Comment: Are you asking about updating apps via the Play Store, or updating apps' content?  Also, it will help to know which Android version you are running on your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option you can use open the menu in play store and then go to Settings and then mark the **Notification:Notify me about updates to apps or games that I downloaded** and then you will get the notification and update them whenever you want to.

[image]

[image]

Also unmark the **Auto-update apps** so it will never update them automatically.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this, except to only select to manually update apps, and them update them when you have your charger connected.

There is no way to automatically restrict them.

Comment: Mmmh, that's too bad. Thanks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about updating apps from the Google Play store, the latest version (v3.10.9 as of this writing) does not have an option for that.

If you are talking about updating content within apps themselves, this depends on each app.  Most apps that connect to the Internet to refresh their content have controls of some sort that allow you to specify the updating frequency based on time of day, and sometimes based on WiFi state. It may be possible to implement refreshing based on charging state (possibly might need root privileges), but that functionality is up to the developers.